# Get the year from a timestamp in R

Tags: r

I have an r dataset which has a list of timestamps like this: `2009-08-18 14:38:20` `2010-08-10 14:58:25`  etc

I want to extract the year but the Posixct doesn't have a years function unlike the `months(t$timestamp)`

Is there a way to get only 2009?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use format:

```
x <- as.POSIXct(c("2009-08-18 14:38:20", "2010-08-10 14:58:25"))
format(x, "%Y")
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried ?

```
strptime(yourtimestamp, "%Y")
```